# Did any WWII aircraft only use a turbocharger but not a supercharger?

Tags: turbocharged, supercharger

In doing some basic research, I have concluded that all WW II aircraft equipped with turbochargers also used mechanical driven centrifugal superchargers.

These include the P-38, P-47, B-17, B-24, B-29, etc.

Is this correct, and are there any exceptions where the engine lacked a mechanical supercharger and only used the turbocharger for boost?

[image: Schematic diagram of turbosupercharged power plant]

Comment: Original poster, if you are able to come up with a good answer to this question, please share it with us.

Comment: This website gives some hints as to why a gear-driven supercharger would normally be used in addition to a turbosupercharger: http://rwebs.net/avhistory/opsman/geturbo/geturbo.htm

Comment: Gear/belt driven supercharger runs at constant speed. I don't think the compressor works well at all altitudes if it has a fixed speed. For a exhaust-driven turbo charger at least you can adjust the waste gate valve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is suggested in the original question, the answer appears to be "no".  This website gives some hints as to why a gear-driven supercharger would normally be used in addition to a turbosupercharger: http://www.rwebs.net/avhistory/opsman/geturbo/geturbo.htm

(Though the link may raise more questions than it answers: it doesn't make it obvious why a turbosupercharger usually injects air upstream of the carburetor, or why a gear-driven supercharger usually injects air downstream of the carburetor, or why only the latter prevents issues with valve cooling.)